# How to use expr within an if condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have the following if condition:

```
STATUSFILE = "foo.status"
NEWTIME=1389253927
if [ -f $STATUSFILE ] && [ expr $NEW_TIME - cat $STATUSFILE -gt 3600 ]; then
    echo "foo"
fi;
```

and I get [: too many arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument of `if` is a unix command. `[` is equivalent to `test`. The result of `if` depends on the return status of that command.

Therefore, if you want to test the return status of a command, you should remove `[`.

When you want to check the output of a command (not its status), you have to keep `[` and put the command in `$(` and `)`.

Your statement should be rewritten as:

```
if [ -f $STATUSFILE ] && [ $(expr $NEWTIME - $(cat $STATUSFILE)) -gt 3600 ]; then
```

Better than that is to use the arithmetic capabilities of bash, provided by `$((` and `))`:

```
if [ -f $STATUSFILE ] && [ $(($NEWTIME - $(cat $STATUSFILE) )) -gt 3600 ]; then
```

Comment: +1, but it's generally best to make prolific use of double-quotes, otherwise any bugs risk becoming impossible to figure out and track down.

Comment: @ruakh: About double quote, I didn't want to confuse the OP and tried to follow its coding style. By the way, thanks for your upvote and your fix.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It worked fine is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: In `bash`, you can use `[[ -f $STATUSFILE ]] && (( NEWTIME - $(<$STATUSFILE) > 3600 ))`; your version is POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You use `foo $(expr 1 + 1)` to use the output from the command `expr 1 + 1` as the argument for the command `foo`. The command `foo expr 1 + 1` simply runs `foo` with the four literal strings `expr`, `1`, `+`, and `1` as its arguments (and I cannot imagine a sane, unambiguous way for it to mean anything else).